# Wifi Router only connected to maximum 5 device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have TP Link TL-WR340G and when I'm trying to connect more than 5 devices, the sixth device cannot connected to my router. I guess is any configuration for limitation of device while connected. I've tried to find that configuration but their not listed in admin console. I cannot figure it out.

How my router can connect with more than 5 devices? Is there I miss?

ps.
I've tried to changed channel to 11 and mode 54Mbps (802.11g) but not solve my problem.

Comment: Sometimes some wifi router has a setting to only allow 5 devices. Another possibility is your DHCP setting is only set to have range of 5 (so even if the next wifi devices connected, it is simply not getting any IP for itself). So if it can't connect at all, it may be device-limited. If you connect, but not getting internet (or not getting IP) then it may be your DHCP setting.

Comment: @Darius I've checked my DHCP setting and starting ip address from 1 to 199 hence i guess problem not came from DHCP configuration. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Another test you can try, drop the 1st device off wifi, and connect the 6th device. Does it work? (just to make sure that it is not the device that is broken/misconfigured)

Comment: @Darius yes 6th device connected after first device i tried to disconnected from wifi network. So what i miss configured?

Comment: I don't own that particular device but in my own wifi router - I have an option to limit the number of clients connected to the wifi. You might have that set to 5. Good luck finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else seems to work you can always try to factory reset your router to see if that helps. 
Source: https://www.router-reset.com/en/reset-manuals/TP-LINK/TL-WR340G-v3

Doing this should flush out any odd configurations that might affect the maximum limit. Alhough it is a slightly old router, I doubt that it would have any problem handling more than 5 clients.

Answer (score 0):

I think this router doesn't have some "maximum clients" option (there's an emulator online -> http://www.tplink.com/resources/simulator/TL-WR340G/userRpm/), and if your DHCP range is larger than 5 it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Ensure that your network mask is 255.255.255.0 (basic settins -> network -> lan). Change start and end address on dhcp server to a lower value, for ex *.100 to *.125, that SOHO routers can't work properly with more than 30 clients (so you don't really need to range *.100-*.254). 
Also look for ARP table (advanced settings -> IP & MAC binding -> ARP List).

Would be great to try other wifi channel, just to avoid co-channel and adjacent problems with other clients.

If everything seems to be ok, then I would suggest to do a factory reset, and then update firmware if problem persist.